# leveldb writebatch concurrency issue

Tags: leveldb

If I have

```
using (WriteBatch batch = new WriteBatch())
{
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        batch.Put(i.ToString(), i.ToString())
    }
    leveld_db.Write(batch);
}
```

from one thread and

```
using (WriteBatch batch = new WriteBatch())
{
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        batch.Put(i.ToString(), (i+1000).ToString())
    }
    leveld_db.Write(batch);
}
```

from another concurrent thread, is there a guarantee that I won't end up with data like `{10, 10} {11, 1011}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you are wondering the thread-safe of WriteBatch operation in leveldb.
**The answer is yes, this operation is thread-safe.** In fact, every operation in leveldb is implemented using WriteBatch:

```
Status DB::Put(const WriteOptions& opt, const Slice& key, const Slice& value) {
  WriteBatch batch;
  batch.Put(key, value);
  return Write(opt, &batch);
}
```

And the write ops is queued to avoid racing:

```
  writers_.push_back(&w);
  while (!w.done && &w != writers_.front()) {
    w.cv.Wait();
  }
  if (w.done) {
    return w.status;
  }
```